# NO definition for 'SetBeforeAccess' TokenCache

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I've directly copied a GitHub sample code and cannot get rid of these errors.

```
Error   CS1061  'TokenCache' does not contain a definition for 'SetBeforeAccess'
```

I've included Microsoft.Identity.Client in my using statements.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace TokenCache1
{
    static class TokenCacheHelper
    {

    public static TokenCache GetUserCache()
    {
        if (usertokenCache == null)
        {
            usertokenCache = new TokenCache();
            usertokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
            usertokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
        }
        return usertokenCache;
    }

    static TokenCache usertokenCache;

    /// <summary>
    /// Path to the token cache
    /// </summary>
    public static string CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "msalcache.txt";

    private static readonly object FileLock = new object();

    public static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        lock (FileLock)
        {
            args.TokenCache.Deserialize(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                ? File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath)
                : null);
        }
    }
```

I'm using .NET4.5 and UWP apps.

Comment: I've run across the same thing.  I was hoping you had an answer by now.  I've noticed that it compiles in .Net Framework libraries, so you might try putting in in a Framework library if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

This could have occurred due to missing [MSAL library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client). It can be installed from NuGet on Visual Studio itself.

On Visual Studio, select the Tools menu, choose NuGet Package Manager, then Package Manager Console, and type the following command:

`Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -Pre`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

TokenCacheExtensions class was not accessible when the reference added from packages\Microsoft.Identity.Client.1.1.3-preview0012\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll

But when I added the reference from

```
packages\Microsoft.Identity.Client.1.1.3-preview0012\lib\net45\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
```

then i was able to access the TokenCacheExtension class.